# How do i also hyperlink the create sheet in my below vba?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've assigned a macro to a cell so when it is clicked it makes a copy of a template sheet, asks what name you want for it, and then adds that name to the next blank cell in a column.

I've had a go at doing it below, it doesn't error, however it also doesn't hyperlink either.

How do i now also make the cell where the name goes hyperlink to that sheet?
Full vba on main sheet:

```vb
Public Sub CopySheetAndRenameByCell()
  Dim newName As String
  Dim Emrange As Range
  Set Emrange = Application.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  On Error Resume Next
  newName = InputBox("Enter the name of the new project", "Copy worksheet", ActiveCell.Value)

  If newName <> "" Then
    Sheets("Project Sheet BLANK").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    Emrange.Value = newName
    Worksheets(newName).Select
    Emrange.Select
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="newName!A1", TextToDisplay:="New sheet"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you record a macro while creating the link, that will give you a good starting point for the code you need to add.

Comment: Where is this code located? Could you share the code of the *assigned* macro? Which cell should contain the hyperlink? Maybe post a screenshot to clarify a bit more. BTW, you don't use `On Error Resume Next` in the way you did.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did that and it didn't really help much..

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have a template project sheet and a homepage sheet. Upon clicking a cell with a "Create Project" message it runs the copysheet bit, which copies that blank template and creates a new sheet with whatever you type in.
It also looks for the next blank spot in the project name column and inputs the same name the copied sheet was called. I'm trying to figure out how to tack on it hyperlinking to that create sheet too.

Comment: I've had a go at working it into my code but can't seem to get it working, can someone help me out with where exactly i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Public Sub CopySheetAndRenameByCell()
    Dim newName As String, Emrange As Range, wsNew As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
    
    newName = InputBox("Enter the name of the new project", _
                       "Copy worksheet", ActiveCell.Value)
    
    If newName <> "" Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        wb.Worksheets("Project Sheet BLANK").Copy _
                      After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        Set wsNew = wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error on rename
        wsNew.Name = newName
        On Error GoTo 0     'stop ignoring errors
        
        Set wsIndex = wb.Worksheets("Index") 'for example
        Set Emrange = wsIndex.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        wsIndex.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Emrange, _
                           Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & wsNew.Name & "'!A1", _
                           TextToDisplay:=wsNew.Name
        'reset font style
        Emrange.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone 
        Emrange.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

        If wsNew.Name <> newName Then 'in case sheet could not be renamed....
            MsgBox "Name provided '" & newName & _
                    "' is not valid as a worksheet name!", vbExclamation
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, and thanks for the additional failsafe in there too!
Will mark your answer as the one but before i do i was just wondering, is there anyway for the text that goes into the C column to not be formatted like a hyperlink? So for example, when it enters the text and hyperlinks it to the newly created sheet, is there a bit of vba code to tell it to not change the font, colour style etc?

Comment: You can change the format after adding the link - see edit above